# Sometimes I wonder if there are some marketing people or trolls around

Tags: support

[TikZ - How can I draw a line through a point on a line, with the new line perpendicular to the old line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200836/tikz-how-can-i-draw-a-line-through-a-point-on-a-line-with-the-new-line-perpen/200841#200841)

[image]

This reply, while theoretically correct and probably quite sound and working, not related to the topic. It already has 3 upvotes. How should one deal with this, if at all?

I do not "hang around" SX a lot but I've noticed on some subsites anyway: that ideas/concepts of alternative software, which was not mentioned by the op, suddenly gets many upvotes. So, mods, should one flag it or rather ignore it?

Comment: rather ignore it :) Related; http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/

Comment: There _may_ be a reason for upvotes for that answer 1. the user is well known for his PSTricks (just for fun ) compact codes at tex.sx 2.Also since people like simple,crisp and fast codes. wait for some time you may have an answer of your choice.

Comment: Summarising that link as I understand it: "as long as it's clear about using an alternative approach, and answers the 'big picture' question then it is fine"

Comment: @texenthusiast I intend to choose my code as the solution. I mean it's practically and most certainly the solution Jake would have posted if he had wanted to (exact reasons not really important now). I get the nbit about the "being known". There was also Qrrrbwdfskdjll... in regards to very skillful solutions who apparently stopped in December '13.

Comment: @percusse Alright, will do. Not that there is some "intended" harm when other skilled users post their answers anyway.

Comment: I once saw a list of (all) the different names, is this list still around somewhere?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Only users with rep > 10k can see the list.

Comment: Herbert is 18. `:)`

Comment: Oh... that makes sense... didn't think of that. (yes I know he wrote the package or something along the lines of deep involvement). Well then, glad it got cleared up. :) His age... I think you are lying. :P

Comment: @henry: Somehow related: [Downvoting answers exploiting different approaches with respect to the initial question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3408/13304).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As none answers this question and based on the given comments above, here the summary.

- As long as the answer shows an alternative approach to solve the problem, it is fine.
- Don't abuse the flag button. Instead, just ignore it by optionally clicking the up vote button.

Comment: no PSTricks fun in this answer? :(

Comment: @dcmst: Upvoting is the best way to ignore. :-)